# Using window builder in eclipse

Tags: swing

I am using the windows builder in eclipse to create a swing application. However I observe that the auto generated code is kind of confusing me.

```
       test frame = new test();
       frame.setVisible(true);


public test() {
        setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        setBounds(100, 100, 450, 300);
        contentPane = new JPanel();
        contentPane.setBorder(new EmptyBorder(5, 5, 5, 5));
        contentPane.setLayout(new BorderLayout(0, 0));
        setContentPane(contentPane);
    }
```

I always thought we needed to create a JFrame and add the panel to it. But here eclipse seems to create a test object using the construcutor and then invoke the frame.setVisible on a class object and it seems to work fine. I thought the frame.setVisible() must always be invoked on a Jframe.

Comment: what is your question?

Comment: I want to know how  test.setVisible() on an object actually works when test is actually a class and not a JFrame. Dont we have to create a JFrame and then add a panel to it?

Comment: execute your code & you will know.

Comment: I dont understand. Can you please explain a little

Answer (score 1):

This `test` class is a `JFrame` see the class definition and you will find it inherits `JFrame` so this should clear your confusion.

Comment: So calling test.setVisible is the same as calling test.getFrame().setVisible()

Comment: test is  **a frame**, so you directly call *test.setVisible();*